# Octave c++ interface: copy data from vector

Tags: c++, octave

I have data stored in a vector that I want to pass into octave for processing but I'm not sure the most efficient way of doing this. With the matlab mwArray I would just do something like :

```
vector<float> vec(100, 0.0);
mwArray data_mw(1, 100, mxSINGLE_CLASS);
data_mw.SetData(vec.data(), vec.size());
```

What I'd like is a similar way of getting data into octave (I assume via FloatMatrix). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There [will be](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/f8212eb6da00) a constructor for that in the upcoming 4.2 release. When that is released, you will be able to do:

```
Array<T> a (your_std_vector, dim_vector (1, 100));
```

In the mean time, you can have your own function:

```
template<typename T>
Array<T>
array_from_vector (const std::vector<T>& v, const dim_vector& dv)
{
  Array<T> a (dv);
  const T* vd = v.data ();
  T* ad = a.fortran_vec ();
  for (octave_idx_type i = 0; i < a.numel (); i++)
    *ad++ = *vd++;
  return a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the expected timing of the 4.2 release?

Comment: @ryan0270 sometime during the fall.